# Kotlin Android: How to pass ArrayList of Serializable objects through intent without unchecked cast warning?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm creating an `Intent` like so:

```
public void showThings(ArrayList<Thing> things) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(THINGS, things);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then in the `ThingActivity` I want to get the `ArrayList<Thing>`

```
class ThingActivity {
   var things: ArrayList<Thing>? = null

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       things = intent.extras.getSerializable(OtherActivity.THINGS) as? ArrayList<Thing>
   }
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to cast to the appropriate type without triggering an "unchecked cast" warning. Is there a way to gracefully set to `null` if (somehow unexpectedly) the cast fails?

Appending `?: return null` does not seem to work as I've seen suggested elsewhere

Comment: In IntelliJ or Android Studio, `Alt+Enter`, left-arrow on the item, suppress for the method, or class, or some other level. Hides the warning

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way with `Bundle`. This library makes use of generics and implements type-safe data passing between `Fragment`s: http://github.com/Miha-x64/Flawless

Comment: Ideally I'd pass whatever test it's expecting me to pass, not a big fan of supressing warnings.

Comment: Honestly? Just suppress that.

Comment: Do you have access to the source of `Thing` ? You could implement `Parcelable` on it and then use the parcelable-related methods of Intent instead of the serializable-related ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unchecked cast warning is happening due to the way Java generics work at runtime. Because of type erasure, at runtime, the type of the list is just `List`, and not `List<Thing>`. That means that the cast is considered unsafe, even though it's quite possible for a human to look at the code and see that there's no problem.

While I agree with you that suppressing the warning isn't ideal, in this case I think it's fine.

The *best* solution, though, would be to implement the `Parcelable` interface on `Thing`. That way, when you want to pass a `List<Thing>` through an intent, you could write:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(THINGS, things)
```

And when you want to read it back out:

```
things = intent.extras.getParcelableArrayListExtra(OtherActivity.THINGS)
```

Neither of these will cause a compiler warning.

Comment: This is good info. I'll read up more about `Parcelable` it seems that it's recommended for passing custom objects through `Intent`s anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Ben P's answer, you could use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Assuming that `Things` is simply a data class (holds a bunch of variables), this will work perfectly (this is also required by Ben P's answer).

Here's a way to implement it:

```
public void showThings(ArrayList<Thing> things) {
    String json = new Gson().toJson(things);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(THINGS, json);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then you can get the ArrayList like this:

```
String json = intent.getStringExtra(THINGS);
TypeToken<ArrayList<Things>> token = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Things>>() {};
ArrayList<Things> things = new Gson().fromJson(json, token.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity one:

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
val arrayGuide = ArrayList<Guide>()
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("arrayInfo",arrayGuide)
startActivity(intent)
```

Activity two:

```
if(intent != null){
  val arrayList = 
  this.intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Guide>("arrayInfo")
}
```